# How to group the image regions of same color and get its coordinates ignoring the background color using python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, semantic-segmentation

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKkly.png)

I need to group the region in green and get its coordinates, like this [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A23bl.png). How to do this in python?

Please see the attached images for better clarity

Comment: We cannot help you until you show what you've already tired

Comment: SO expects some minimal research effort. Look into opencv please

Comment: i haven't stated anything regarding this. Basically i'm trying to identify image regions from document image. I trained a semantic segmentation model to do this and the input image is the model output. from the output i need to group those green regions which are actually images and get its coordinates. if the region is fully green (like green block) i can use connected components to get the region coordinates. but here since it has background color also visible( black color) CC is not working. IDK how to proceed further

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527769/removing-black-background-and-make-transparent-from-grabcut-output-in-python-ope

Comment: "I trained a semantic segmentation model"... show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

At first, `split` the green channel of the image, put a `threshold` on that and have a binary image. This binary image contains the objects of the green area. Start `dilating` the image with the suitable kernel, this would make adjacent objects stick to each other and become to one big object. Then use `findcontour` to take the sizes of all objects, then hold the biggest object and remove the others, this image would be your mask. Now you can `reconstruct` the original image (green channel only) with this mask and fit a box to the remained objects.

You can easily find the code each part.